# get n-th child of a <tr>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
$('.odd, .even').each(function(i, obj) {
    $(obj:nth-child(3));
});
```

I wonder why this gives me an error? I wanted to get the 3rd child of a td.
Which has the following structure:

```
<tr class="odd">
        <td class=" sorting_1"><input name="pid" type="checkbox" value="3350360"></td>
        <td class=" ">bravejournal</td>

        <td class=" ">
            <a href="http://anonym.to/?http://gerrsad123yymqe.bravejournal.com" target="_blank">http://gerrsad123yymqe.bravejournal.com</a>

        </td>

    </tr>
```

In the final result I basically wanted to get the value of :

```
http://gerrsad123yymqe.bravejournal.com
```

any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if that is always going to be third, you can use `:eq(2)`

```
$('.odd, .even').each(function(i, obj) {
    $('td:eq(2)',this).find('a').attr('href');
});
```

if that is always going to be the last one , you can use `:last`

```
$('td:last',this).find('a').attr('href'); // or .text() if you want text inside <a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is syntactically incorrect, `obj` is the `tr` element so use that element reference along with child selector like

```
$('.odd, .even').each(function(i, obj) {
    $(obj).children(':nth-child(3)');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `.find()` here since `obj` is currently your `tr` element with class `odd` or `even`:

```
$('.odd, .even').each(function(i, obj) {
    $(obj).find('td:nth-child(3)');
});
```

In stead of `nth-child`m you can also use `.eq()`:

```
$('.odd, .even').each(function(i, obj) {
    $(obj).find('td').eq(2);
});
```

or `:eq()` selector:

```
$('.odd, .even').each(function(i, obj) {
    $(obj).find('td:eq(2)');
});
```

Note that `:eq()` or `.eq()` is 0-based index so you need to use `2` here to get the third td.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
$('.odd, .even').each(function() {
  var td = $(this).find('td').eq(2);
});
```